# Adding more values to a key in a dictionary without overwriting the existing value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a bingo game where the user is guessing on five numbers and the computer takes out ten random numbers between 1-26.

The part I am having trouble with is that when the user have guessed, the numbers have been compared and added to the dictionary. If I then play the "game" once more it overwrites the last rounds points (which I want to keep).

```
def user_vs_cpu(cpu_random):

    global players
    for player in players:
        correct_guess = 0
        for guess in player["guess"]:
            for bingo_number in cpu_random:
                if guess == bingo_number:
                    correct_guess += 1
        player["points"] = {correct_guess}
    print(players)
```

`players` is a list that contains the dictionaries.

cpu_random is the computer's randomly generated numbers.

`player["points"]` is where the compared points is stored.

-edit-
I forgot to mention is that there is more dicts in the list players so that i can add more players to the game.

Comment: this is a program-logic problem - copy the total amount of points of player somewherre to keep it -f.e. `player_rounds["round1"] = player["points"]` ...your code is not a [mcve] so it is hard to advice.#

Comment: Alternatviely, make `player["points"]` a `list` of values instead a single value, then, after each round, _append_ another value to it.

Comment: I do see what you are saying, I do have a hard time to create this into a smaller code due to my inexperience. My problem still remains, the add function that i use for other keys in the dictionary looks the same as player["points"] = {correct_guess}if that helps?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding how to make player["points"] into a list?

Comment: Initialize it to `[]` or `list()`. If you include more code in your question, I could be more specific...

Answer (score 0):

With `player["points"] = {correct_guess}` you're **correct_guess** variable turns into a **set** object due to the curly braces. You could then operate with this object according to [PythonDocs Set Types](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset). That's not what you want. Like suggested try to work with a list with **append** or use an integer if only the current points are important, this would be for example:
`player["points"] += 1`

[See also 'PythonDocs Data Structures'](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Suggestion: Try to get familiar with a good IDE like PyCharm, set a BreakPoint to `player["points"] = {correct_guess}` and see where you going wrong (you will be able to see the state of all variables/objects simultaneously.